# Roll back save/roster move in NBA 2K15

Tags: nba2k15

In myGM mode in NBA2k15, I accidentally simmed through free agency and, in doing so, lost my best player who was unsigned (Anthony Davis). He signed to another team, and I have no idea what to do . Is there a way to either reload a previous save or force a trade so that I can get him back?

Answer (score 1):

If you select the stats of all the teams you can actually call the team that has Anthony Davis and request a trade for your players or draft picks for next year if they have the money to sign your traded players.